# Singleton example from "The Ruby Programming Language" results in 'undefined method' or uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby, singleton

Working through "The Ruby Programming Language" and attempting to implement the Singleton example from the end of Chapter 7, section "Object Creation and Initialization"

The chapter works with a "Point" class, which is gradually extended to include class instance variables and Class methods to allow for the recording of "point stats" - the number of points created and their average values.

Able to get this to work fine: [working without singleton](https://github.com/michaeldayreads/0_autodidact/blob/master/ruby/theRubyProgramingLanguage/ch7_points.rb)

When I refactored to have a `PointStats` Singleton class and a `Point` class, I find I either get a `undefined method x` error when `PointStats` class is first, or a `uninitialized constant PointStats` error when `Point` class is first.

Running 1.8 on OSX, though also tried on another machine running 2.0 via rvm - same results from lines of interest.

I must be missing something very basic about how to have multiple classes in Ruby work together.

*What am I doing incorrect?* As near as I can tell I am following the example from the book exactly, yet each class seems to require that the other be defined first.

refactored code with PointStats class first, as suggested by text:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'singleton'

class PointStats
    include Singleton

    def initialize
        @n, @totalX, @totalY = 0, 0.0, 0.0
    end

    def record(point)
        @n += 1
        @totalX += point.x
        @totalY += point.y
    end

    def report
        puts "#{@n} -- points"
        puts "#{@totalX/@n} -- Average x"
        puts "#{@totalY/@n} -- Average y"       
    end

end

class Point

    def initialize(x,y)
        @x,@y = x,y
        PointStats.instance.record(self)
    end

    ORIGIN = Point.new(0,0)
    UNIT_X = Point.new(1,0)
    UNIT_Y = Point.new(0,1)

    include Enumerable
    include Comparable

    attr_reader :x, :y

    def to_s
        "(#{@x},#{@y})"
    end

    def +(other)
        Point.new(@x + other.x, @y + other.y)
    rescue
        raise TypeError,
            "Point like argument expected"
    end

    def -@
        Point.new(-@x, -@y)
    end

    def *(scalar)
        Point.new(@x*scalar, @y*scalar)
    end

    def coerce(other)
        [self, other]
    end

    def [](index)
        case index
        when 0, -2: @x
        when 1, -1: @y
        when :x, "x": @x
        when :y, "y": @y
        else nil
        end
    end

    def each
        yield @x
        yield @y
    end

    def ==(o)
        if 0.is_a? Point
            @x==o.x && @y==o.y
        else
            false
        end
    end

    def eql?(o)
        if o.instance_of? Point
            @x.eql?(o.x) && @y.eql?(o.y)
        else
            false
        end
    end

    def hash
        code = 17
        code = 37*code + @x.hash
        code = 37*code + @y.hash
        code
    end

    def <=>(other)
        return nil unless other.instance_of? Point
        @x**2 + @y**2 <=> other.x**2 + other.y**2
    end

    def self.sum(*points)
        x = y = 0
        points.each { |p| x+=p.x; y+=p.y }
        Point.new(x,y)
    end

end
```

---

Edit: thanks @cozyconemotel -- went with two public methods, leaving the `new` to behave in a more expected fashion and adding `unrecorded` for other uses:

```
    class Point
        attr_reader :x, :y

        def initialize(x,y)
            @x,@y = x,y
            PointStats.instance.record(self)
        end

        def self.unrecorded(x,y)
            instance = new(x,y)
        end

        ORIGIN = Point.unrecorded(0,0)
        UNIT_X = Point.unrecorded(1,0)
        UNIT_Y = Point.unrecorded(0,1)

        # and the rest follows ...
```

Comment: @sawa - how do I get these two classes to work together? As near as I can tell I am following the example from the book exactly.

Answer (score 1):

As @guitarman has pointed out, because a call to `PointStats.instance.record` requires `Point#x and Point#y`, you have to move `attr_reader :x, :y` to before `initialize` to make it work.

```
class Point
  attr_reader :x, :y
  def initialize(x,y)
    @x,@y = x,y
    PointStats.instance.record(self)
  end
  #(rest of the class def..)
end
```

I found another problem in your code though. In your definition for `Point` you are creating 3 instances:

```
ORIGIN = Point.new(0,0)
UNIT_X = Point.new(1,0)
UNIT_Y = Point.new(0,1)
```

The problem is that these also trigger calls to `PointStats.instance.record`, and therefore this happens

```
> p1 = Point.new(10,10) 
=> #<Point:0x007ff7935d6f78 @x=10, @y=10>
> p2 = Point.new(20,20) 
=> #<Point:0x007ff7935f4b68 @x=20, @y=20>
> PointStats.instance.report
5 -- points
6.2 -- Average x
6.2 -- Average y
=> nil
```

One thing you should do is make `new` private and create a factory method that calls `record`. Like this:

```
class Point
  attr_reader :x, :y
  private_class_method :new

  def initialize(x,y)
    @x,@y = x,y
  end

  def self.generate(x,y)
    instance = new(x,y)
    PointStats.instance.record(instance)
    instance
  end

  ORIGIN = new(0,0)
  UNIT_X = new(1,0)
  UNIT_Y = new(0,1)

  #(here goes the rest..)
end
```

You don't have to make `new` private if you simply want to use both `new` (create new instance without recording) and `generate` (create new instance that is recorded).

Answer (score 0):

That's because you deliver the new point in the initialize method of the Point class to the `record(self)` method of the PointStats class where you access `point.x` before your point defines the getter methods via `attr_reader :x, :y`. 
Move `attr_reader :x, :y` to the first line within `class Point`, because your script will be interpreted from top to bottom.